# Formatting Strings and String arrays with tabs in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, tabs, string.format

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to have a method that formats an array of `String` objects to be tabulated a certain way with a header, and put all the objects (after being formatted) nicely into a single `String` for the method to return. This method is inside an object class, so it ultimately will be formatting multiple objects the same way, so I need it to format the same way with various `String` lengths.

Here's what I need the output to look like:

```
      Hashtags:
                #firstHashtag
                #secondHashtag
```

Each hashtag is in a `String[]` of hashtags,

i.e. 
`String[] hashtags = ["#firstHashtag", "#secondHashtag"]`

So basically I need to use `string.format()` to create on single string containing a tabbed "Hashtags:" header, and then each String in the "hashtags" array to be on a new line, and double-tabbed. The size of the "hashtag" array changes since it is in an object class.

Could someone help me use String.formatter?

This is what my method looks like so far:

```
public String getHashtags()
     {
          String returnString = "Hashtags:";
          String add;
          int count = 0;

          while(count < hashtags.length)
          {
               //hashtags is an array of String objects with an unknown size

               returnString += "\n";
               add = String.format("%-25s", hashtags[count]);

               //here I'm trying to use .format, but it doesn't tabulate, and I 
               //don't understand how to make it tabulate!!
               count++;
               returnString = returnString + add;
          }

          if(hashtags == null)
          {
               returnString = null;
          }

          return returnString;

     }
```

Any helpful advice on what to do here with formatting would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use real tabs and not spaces, then just change your program to be like this one:

```
public String getHashtags()
 {
      if(hashtags == null)
      {
           return null;
      }

      String returnString = "Hashtags:";
      int count = 0;

      while(count < hashtags.length)
      {
           //hashtags is an array of String objects with an unknown size

           returnString = returnString + "\n\t\t"+hashtags[count];
           count++;
      }

      return returnString;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String.format() statement will create a String that is left-justified and padded to 25 spaces. For example, this line:

```
System.out.println("left-justified  >" + String.format("%-25s", "hello") + "<");
```

outputs:

```
left-justified  >hello                    <
```

The other thing is that you're not really using tabs (I don't see the tab character in your program). String.format() is creating Strings that are length 25 and left-justified. Keep that in mind as you create the return string. Also, your loop as adding a newline character each time. That's why you're getting multi-line output.